# Change wordpress navbar to link straight to post or page

Tags: wordpress, templates

The template I am using is techified and I would like to change the navbar to link directly to the post, not the category as it does now.

Here is the code for header.php. I'm assuming this would be where the change would be made.

```
<div id="navigation_area">
<ul id="nav">
<?php wp_list_categories('exclude=1&hide_empty=0&orderby=name&show_count=0&use_desc_for_title=1&title_li='); ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would using `<?php wp_list_pages( $args ); ?>` instead of `list categories` work?